# I want to write a multiple condition query to display result from Table

Tags: mysql

I have a table named info which has 3 columns: Id, city, country.
I need to filter the table. That is, when i search for city and country it should show me the exact row but when i will search only for the country it should show all the cities in that country. how can i write the condition?

[How it is looking right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPKTU.png)

I have tried using AND and OR but they only do one task. my current query

```
SELECT * FROM info WHERE name='$_POST[name1]' AND country='$_POST[country1]';
```

this work for both fields and

```
SELECT * FROM info where name='$_POST[name1]' OR country='$_POST[country1]';
```

this fails when searched on both fields at once

Comment: try using like instead of where

Comment: I think you should probably use two separate SQL statements and choose the one to execute based on the provided query data. I assume there is some way to achieve this in a single query by using conditional joins of the table with itself, but this will result in a very complex query that does not perform well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$condition = '';
$query = ''
if(!empty($_POST[name1])) { $condition .= "and name LIKE '$_POST[name1]' "; }
if(!empty($_POST[country1])){ $condition .= "and country LIKE '$_POST[country1]' "; }
$query = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE Id !='' " . $condition;

mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

Comment: what should i put at $qry ? BTW thank you very much for helping me with this .

Comment: $qry is just a variable if name1 , country1 is not empty it creating query like this using  concatenation (.) operator so that .query formed like this

Comment: and also you have define $qry=''; in top of code starting

Comment: Thank you so much it is working right now, you are a life saver. 
i changed the code because it was giving me mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 error. the new code is :



if(empty($_POST['name1'])){
 $sqlsearch="SELECT * FROM info WHERE name='$_POST[name1]' OR country='$_POST[country1]' ";
}else{

 $sqlsearch="SELECT * FROM info WHERE name='$_POST[name1]' AND country='$_POST[country1]'";
}


Thank you so much for helping me with it.

Comment: are you got solution ? if not mean please post the full code i will give exact solution for it

Answer (score 0):

Both name and country are varchar so use LIKE in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM info WHERE name LIKE '$_POST[name1]' OR country LIKE '$_POST[country1]';
```

try this.

Comment: Now when i search for both fields it fails. ex if i search for name new york and country US it shows all the US fields. New York ,new jersey etc.